# Реализация метода объектов одного класса

Tags: java

```
public class A {
int x =5;

public void method () 
{
 x=x + 1; //просто пример
}
}
```

У меня сто экземпляров класса А. Как сделать, чтобы этот метод использовался одновременно во всех объектах данного класса?  Если его сделать ***static***, он будет использоваться для всех объектов? Или поля класса должны быть тоже Статичными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременно - никак. <s>Ну, вы конечно, можете запустить 100 параллельных потоков, работающих одновременно, но запускаться они тоже же будут последовательно... Возможно, если у вас будет 100 ядерное устройство и сверх точные часы вы сможете запустить на каждом ядре одновременно в заданное время этот метод...</s>

Можно последовательно:

1. Поместить все экземпляры класса `A` в список/массив.
2. Пройтись по списку/массиву циклом и вызвать нужный метод у экземпляра.

Статический метод/переменная один на все экземпляры класса. Метод сей не может обращаться к нестатическим полям класса.

Comment: Ахахах))) 
быстро и понятно :) 
Спасибо )